# vertical alignment issue in table cell, flowdocument C#

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, tablecell

I am trying to print table using flow-document

I created a table as shown in the figure below, but the cells are not aligned vertically.

I want to center vertical alignment in table cell.

What should I try?

```
<FlowDocument>
        <Table>
            <TableRowGroup>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell Background="Green" RowSpan="2">
                        <Paragraph>Cell 1</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph Background="Yellow">Cell 2</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell Background="Red">
                        <Paragraph>Cell 1</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>

                </TableRow>
            </TableRowGroup>
        </Table>
</FlowDocument>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcHVt.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cells always have the same height, you can offset the paragraph by a margin of 10 at the top and get the text centered:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Table>
        <TableRowGroup>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell Background="Green" RowSpan="2" TextAlignment="Center">

                    <Paragraph Margin="0,10,0,0">Cell 1</Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
                
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph Background="Yellow">Cell 2</Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell Background="Red">
                    <Paragraph>Cell 1</Paragraph>
                </TableCell>

            </TableRow>
        </TableRowGroup>
    </Table>
</FlowDocument>
```